# How to change the parameter name using resources in Phoenix framework Router without affecting sub resources

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
resources "/rooms", RoomController, only: [:show, :update, :delete], param: "room_id", name: "" do
          resources "/users", UserController, except: [:create], param: "user_id"
          resources "/notes", NoteController, except: [:delete, :update], param: "note_id"
          resources "/messages", MessageController, except: [:delete, :update], param: "message_id"
end
```

I have those resources. It gives me routes like this: /api/v1/rooms/:_room_id/users/:user_id

How to remove that underscore before "room_id"?

Is separation like this is good solution:

```
resources "/rooms", RoomController, only: [:show, :update, :delete], param: "room_id"

resources "/rooms", RoomController, only: [] do
    resources "/users", UserController, except: [:create], param: "user_id"
    resources "/notes", NoteController, except: [:delete, :update], param: "note_id"
    resources "/messages", MessageController, except: [:delete, :update], param: "message_id"
end
```

EDIT:

I want to have :room_id for every resource with room:

```
DELETE /api/v1/rooms/:room_id/
GET /api/v1/rooms/:room_id/users/:user_id
```

If I use resources without param, then I'll have:

```
DELETE /api/v1/rooms/:id/
GET /api/v1/rooms/:room_id/users/:user_id
```

If I use resources with param ("room_id"):

```
DELETE /api/v1/rooms/:room_room_id/
GET /api/v1/rooms/:room_id/users/:user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The option `name: ""` adds the string `""` as a prefix to the parameter together with a separating underscore. If you remove the `name: ""` option you should be good.

Here's the documentation https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4

Comment: In this case I will have /api/v1/rooms/:room_room_id/users/:user_id

Comment: Yes, that's right. The preferable way would be to just remove `name` and `param` and accept that the input is called `:room_id` in `UserController` and `:id` in `RoomController`. Isn't that working for you?

Comment: Just wondered if I can have :room_id for any endpoint. Guess I can't :) Thank you for your answer!